# Ultrasound Vegetable Glycerin homogenization

Tags: physical-chemistry

We are trying to homogenize VG (USP) with propylene-glycol using ultrasonic homogenizer with titanium probe, but we are experiencing very strange - bad odor from the emulsion after sonication. 
We tried different amplitudes, different time settings, different power settings. We can control amplitude for 2 modes only, I believe they are 50% and 100%.
Also if I am sonicating pure vegetable oil for just 5-10 sec I can smell that strange odor, it is very similar to that, I am getting with VG.
I just want to know, what this smell can come from? From our probe? No it is clean, we can sonicate water well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on intensity, ultrasound can produce *intense* heat at some locations. In fact, [cavitation can induce temperatures far exceeding **5,000 K**.](https://www.hielscher.com/ultrasonic-cavitation-in-liquids-2.htm) Even a small ultrasonic room humidifier can burn through a plastic comb held in the upwelling stream. The sound intensity is decomposing the oil and/or propylene glycol.

Try lower frequencies and lower sound intensity. You might experiment with different shape containers, as well, to avoid focusing the sound into a high-intensity spot.

Comment: Can you recommend device that is perfect to work with vegetable glycerin? I am accepting the answer, but wanted more information. Can't find any special info about VG and sonication, in my case sonication is used for homogenization process only.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have actual experience with using ultrasound for homogenization. You might compare your design with a mayonnaise emulsifier, though: http://www.hyfoma.com/en/content/food-branches-processing-manufacturing/oil-margarines-sauces/mayonnaise/. These rely on mechanical stirring and use of a lecithin (egg-yolk for mayonnaise) to form the emulsion.